# tableView not loading data

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview

I've a 2 items tabBar application wich loads relevant text from the RSS feed of 2 different URLs and then shows the data from the url1 in tableview1 and the data from url2 in tableview2.

The app starts and loads url1data into tableview1 but when you switch to tableview2 the url2data is loaded into the tableview1 displaying both url1 and url2data in tableview1 while tableview2 remains empty.

Any ideas of what could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you seperating the data from url1 and url2?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IB, check the delegate, dataSource & tableView you link up whether it is to the correct tables. Otherwise, check your codes that does this.